# Not a floating point valid. Message error Python

Tags: python, error-handling, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Well, I'm learning how to use Python, I'm using turtle-graphics to do a menu, in one part I ask for a number with

```
def getNumber():
    return screen.numinput("Title"," Enter a number...")
```

Running the program, when I call this function and insert a letter or nothing and , I get an error: "Not a floating point valid. Please try again" in a window. So, Is there a way to change the message?, I would like to change that message to "Enter a number, not a letter!" or something like that.

Comment: @devnull Adding a try .. except don't catch the error :/ It still showing the message.

Answer (score 0):

edited:

```
import sys, tkMessageBox

def getNumber():
    try:
        return screen.numinput('Title', 'Enter a number...')
    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror(title='Wrong Input',message='Enter a valid number!')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is not what I want, with "screen.numinput" I get a window asking for a number, not from the Python shell :(

Comment: @ nanokuro edited the code.  does this work or are you still getting that error window?

Comment: @ Amazingred I still getting the error :S [link](http://k41.kn3.net/F/8/5/C/E/9/CA7.png)

Answer (score 0):

All user input is always a string. You must explicitly convert the string to a number:

```
result = float(getNumber())
```

-or-

```
def getNumber():
    s = screen.numinput("Title"," Enter a number...")
    return float(s)
```